# how to observe the events or detect the notification when the iOS system announce over a button or a label when VoiceOver is running?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility-notification

When VoiceOver is running, I tapped a button, or a label, it will announce something about this button or label.
I want to do something when announcement completed. Is there some notifications to help me observe when the announcement is completed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, no. However, and this is a terrible hack, you *can* monitor announcements that you, yourself, issue with `UIAccessibilityPostNotification()` by subscripting to the `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinishNotification`. Provided you queue up speech at the right times, it may be a reasonable assumption that any of your announcements *finishing* indicates that all system announcements have ended.